# GCP Node Server Initiates But I Can't Connect to the IP Address

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my new web application (note, this is my first time at this). I am unable to connect to the IP address on port 8080. Things I have successfully done, or at least I think so:

- Opened firewall to http-server-8080 as well as opened both http and https checkboxes
- Executed the startup script
- Allowed port 0.0.0.0 from MongoDB cluster to ensure I can connect
- Run `node server.js` and it starts on port 8080

The browser error message I get at http://34.173.96.254:8080/ is "This site can't be reached. 34.173.96.254 refused to connect." I have verified this is the correct external IP address that GCP is trying to reach. Through GCP network troubleshooting, it says a packet could be delivered. When I ping this URL, it is down despite my server.js running on the GCP virtual machine instance.

This is my minimized server.js code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';


const app = express();

// this is for socket.io
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 //this gets the paths correct for finding things like css/styles.css. __dirname doesn't work with import now, so I had to add all of this other stuff
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv:xxxxx", { useNewUrlParser: true});

// const models = require('./models');
import { Player, Game } from './models.js';

// initialize the game
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index",
    );
});

// for socket.io to note a player connected or disconnected
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

// lots of code here;

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("server started on port 8080");
});
```

And the javascript game code:

```
var socket = io();

console.log("Game begun");
   
document.getElementById("sceneImageID").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("sceneImageID").setAttribute("src","Media/Leavetakings/backpack_wide_2.jpg");
document.getElementById("introMessageID").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("introMessageID").innerHTML = "Welcome to the game! First, a few questions...";

//lots of code;
```

Any ideas what could be causing this inability to connect to the URL? Happy to add more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The service is binded to 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: I haven't come across needing to do that. I'm doing this on Google Cloud Compute VM, is it necessary in this case?

Comment: What are you binding to? `0.0.0.0` means bind/listen on all network interfaces. If you are using something else, then make sure you understand what interface(s) you are binding/listening on. However, your problem might be that your application is hung waiting for MongoDB to respond which means your app cannot respond. Edit your question and include the code. Read this guide when posting questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `server.listen(8080, ''0.0.0.0', function() {...}`? and restarting the process.

Comment: I tried adding that code, but it didn't seem to change anything. I'm at the point where opening the firewall to 0.0.0.0/0 at Mongodb doesn't crash the server.js, but I still cannot see my program running at the external IP address ("refused to connect").